# Javascript parsing text data error?

Tags: javascript, parsing, filereader, papaparse

I'm trying to parse some data from my local directory. 
I use papa parser to do it. 
The problem is I can't assign text file into a variable. I'm getting this error ;

**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**

I've searched about it and I've seen that it is a very common error when reading files with HTML file reader .

My code is ;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <script src="https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/blob/master/papaparse.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Parse Example</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <p>Click the button to Upload .</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" type="INPUT">Load</button>
    <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    <script>
        var x;
        var config = {
            delimiter: "", // auto-detect
            newline: "", // auto-detect
            header: true,
            dynamicTyping: false,
            preview: 0,
            encoding: "",
            worker: false,
            comments: false,
            step: undefined,
            complete: undefined,
            error: undefined,
            download: true,
            skipEmptyLines: false,
            chunk: undefined,
            fastMode: undefined,
            beforeFirstChunk: undefined,
            withCredentials: undefined
        };
        function myFunction() {
            x = document.getElementsByName("datafile");
            myfile =  Papa.parse(x, config);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myfile;
        }
    </script>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `getElementsByName` returns always returns nodelist collection of the matched elements, so basically you can just select first one: `x = document.getElementsByName("datafile")[0]`
2. `Papa.parse` expects its first argument to be string or `File` object. `File` object can be obtained from `FileList`, which stored in `files` property of the file input. So basically (it should work if file is selected in the input):
   `x = document.getElementsByName("datafile")[0].files[0]`
3. As [documentaion](http://papaparse.com/docs#local-files) says `Papa.parse` doesn't return anything itself, you should provide callback to get the data. So if you replace `complete: undefined` in `config` object with something like

   ```
   complete: function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   }
   ```

   you'll get your data displayed in the browser console.

Comment: It has worked but what if I have a longer document at the first place ? Do I need a for loop to fetch each line ?

Comment: Didn't get the question, could you explain?

Comment: The code has worked. But not the way I wanted . I don't get any errors and my data is not readed as well. I get an empty array-like object after data read. I'm asking is it because line structure ? For example should I write a loop like ;

for i = 0 to line_lenght
line(i) = x = document.getElementsByName("datafile")[i].files[i]

Comment: I've updated the answer: you have to use callback to get your data.First two sections have nothing to do with line structure: first section is just about getting your HTML node, you could use `document.getElementById` method, which returns single node and first `[0]` might be thrown away. Second section is all about getting file object from file input